# Vuetify: How to use my own component inside of a Vuetify Expansion Panel Component

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm just starting with VueJS and Vuetify, so maybe this is a very basic error..

I'm trying to use the vuetify exansion panel component: https://vuetifyjs.com/components/expansion-panels

Basically I want to define my own component to use as **v-expansion-panel-content** but I can't make it work.

What I could make work was define 2 components, one for the header and another one for the content and use them inside of the **v-expansion-panel-content**

But when I try to encapsulate all in 1 component the expansion panel shows the header but it will not expands to show the item content.

Thanks in advance.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/arcard/pen/YEJrZd

HTML:

```
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <div slot="header">Item - without use of component - works OK</div>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="grey lighten-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>

    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <vc-prod-header slot="header"></vc-prod-header>
      <vc-prod-content></vc-prod-content>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>

    <!-- this one doesn't work -->
    <vc-exp-panel-comp></vc-exp-panel-comp>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('vc-prod-header',{
  template: `
    <div>Item - using 2 components: one for the header and one for the content - works OK</div>
  `
});

Vue.component('vc-prod-content',{
  template: `
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="grey lighten-3">component 2:  content</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
  `
});

Vue.component('vc-exp-panel-comp',{
  template: `
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <div slot="header">component title - this one will not expand to show the content</div>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="grey lighten-3">component body: this is now showing</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

Comment: it looks like this may be an actual bug. on click of the expansion arrow, the expansion-panel__container should gain a class of expansion-panel__container--active and the expansion-panel__body should switch to display: block. 
Since neither happens, this implies that the toggle method isn't firing. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/src/components/VExpansionPanel/VExpansionPanelContent.js 
You could report this as an issue to Vuetify, or you could just use method 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after your response I found a fix related to this issue (from 3 days ago) that is pending to be merged: [github bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2617) regards